# Mysql delete rows with local var working partially

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have three tables: utenti, giocate and giocatori.

I have to delete the rows in giocatori and giocate tables where have a certain ids.

I get the ids in this way:

```
SELECT
    @ids:=giocate.id
  FROM
    giocate
  JOIN
    utenti ON utenti.id = giocate.id_account
  WHERE
    utenti.id = 642 AND DATE_FORMAT(giocate.time,
    '%Y-%m-%d') = '2016-03-20';
```

And this works, in fact a

```
SELECT @ids;
```

give me

```
ids
-------
1225
4545
5454
6653
...
```

But when I call this query:

```
DELETE giocate.*, giocatori.*
FROM
  giocatori
INNER JOIN
  giocate
WHERE
  giocate.id_giocatore = giocatori.id AND giocate.id IN (@ids)
```

I get deleted ONLY ONE row in every table...
So I have to repeat that query for the "count(@ids)"...
Why this?

Comment: You need a parameter per value for `IN`, you can't use a single parameter and pass in a comma separated list for example.

Comment: why do you want to do this with a variable ? is there is reason ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen Yeah, because mysql do not let me do nested queries if I delete rows from them (giocate table is both in the delete and select statements)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I am passing an array of values I think... it' s not?

Comment: @Francesco - little trick : DELETE .... FROM ... WHERE xx IN ( SELECT * FROM ( SELECT id FROM sammeTable....) AS tmp( . So MySQL cant see the nested queries

Comment: @BerndBuffen You don't generally need that trick, just use a `JOIN` as in Gordon Linoff's answer.

Comment: @Barmar - yes i know and have up-vote Gordon Linoff's answer, but sometime it easy/faster to do so

Comment: I can't reproduce the result you show. I see that output when I do the original `select @ids := ...` query, but when I do `select @ids;` after that it just shows the ID from the last row of the first query. Which is what I expect, since MySQL doens't have array variables.

Comment: I did that query some days ago, maybe I don't remember exactly the output, goot to know that mysql have no arrays... but if I need to store values as array in a local var how can I do?? (it seems a great limitation...) @Barmar

Comment: @Francesco If I need to save the result of a query, I use a temporary table.

Comment: @Barmar thanks! now I know temporaly table too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrg.  You don't need variables.  This is probably sufficient:

```
DELETE ge, gi
FROM giocatori gi INNER JOIN
     giocate ge
     ON gi.id_giocatore = ge.id 
WHERE ge.id_account = 642
       date(ge.time) = '2016-03-20';
```

This seems to capture the intention of your logic.  However, it might be missing `giocate` records that are on other dates, if that is possible with your data structure.

Comment: Yeah, this is a smarter query, but I still miss the point, WHY my query delete ONLY ONE row? (I expected it to delete all the rows in the @ids var...)

Comment: @Francesco MySQL doesn't have arrays, a variable can only hold one value at a time. I can't reproduce the `select @ids;` behavior you describe in the question.

Comment: `SELECT @variable := column FROM ...` gives you as many rows of output as there are rows found by the query, but the value of the variable *changes with each row* and after the query finishes, the variable is set to the *last* (scalar) value assigned, which is most likely going to be the value from the last row returned, though this is technically not deterministic.

Comment: @Francesco . . . because `giocate.id IN (@ids)` contains only *one* item in the `IN` list -- a string with a bunch of commas.  However, MySQL converts the value to an integer, which in essence peels the first value from the list for the comparison.